# Proxy settings in Firefox don't "stick"

Tags: javascript, firefox, proxy

At home we have a proxy server. At work we don't. Firefox irritates in this regard: whenever I launch it, it defaults to the proxy server. If I do Tools>Options>Settings and select "No proxy", no problem. However, if I shutdown Firefox and restart it, I have to do the Tools>Options>Settings thing all over again because the "No proxy" setting doesn't "stick".

How do I make it stick? Alternatively, can someone suggest a bit of javascript that I can assign to a button on my toolbar which will toggle between the two states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FoxyProxy](http://foxyproxy.mozdev.org/), much more flexible to configure

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a recent windows-only regression in Firefox.

It was hard to track down, basically I got lucky...

Here's the meta bug:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=448634

Here's where the fix was put in.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446536

I haven't had time to verify it, my windows system is dead right now, so I have to do it via bugmail.

Comment: Nice that it got identified as an error and dealt with. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I used a local automatic proxy configuration script for years with great success.  The trick was identifying from the URL or IP address where I was.

/Allan