# Creating robust HTTP connection for dummy users with WinINET

Tags: winapi, proxy, wininet, winhttp

I'm making a program which downloads a simple file from internet on Windows, using
Wininet family API because I want to utilize its IE-compatible proxy behavior. As you all know, current IE has several proxy settings: auto-detect (WPAD), auto-configure (PAC), manually single URL, proxy servers per protocol, socks, direct, ... For most users, the "direct download" works fine; however for some users (especially those behind firewall / NAT), they always need special proxy settings when making connections.

It's painful to write code to handle all these cases so I hope WinINET with `InternetOpen (INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG)` can help me. It does for most users, however I still find some users complaining connection failure. These user may have very special network environments (eg, need username/password auth for proxy) and direct connection does not work for them.

Sometimes dummy users had wrong configuration, and I'd like wininet to try "all" possible proxy settings for me; unfortunately the `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG` will only try the one that user configured, not "every possible proxy settings".

So my question is, how do I make a program with most strong ability to workaround all http connection (especially for proxy configuration) for dummy users (i.e, they don't understand how to configure their system)?
Is there any suggested way to make HTTP connections without the need to take care of proxy stuff? (i.e., a "super" connection solver which will try all possible proxy settings), or if there's any method to tell WinINET to enable all its proxy settings to create connection?

Comment: Francis, I've encountered this problem.  The simple solution does not exist; there are too many variables and grinding through the scenarios as Justin describes is the only sure-fire method.  Even worse, that is all only for Internet Explorer -- with the growing market share of Firefox, methods to get Firefox proxy settings should be added for a complete list.

Comment: @J.J. - Good point.  I thought about the firefox case when I originally wrote the answer and was going to come back to add a step about Firefox. Your comments reminded me to do this!  See new step #4 below. :-)

Comment: Too bad there is no simple solution... It's also interesting that there's also no library wrapping all these painful stuff. I've tried libcurl and libproxy, but they are in fact working in their own way and does not really work like IE's way.

Answer (score 5):

A reasonable algorithm would be this:

1. try a connection using the user's current proxy settings (the ones that IE uses). These are the ones most likley to be working.  See [`WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384096(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN to get these settings, or `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG` in WinINet.
2. if that fails, try a direct connection.
3. if that fails, try a WPAD autodetection using [WinHttpGetProxyForUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384097(VS.85).aspx).  ([WPAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) is the automated way that clients can find a [Proxy Auto-Config (PAC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file on a network, typically a corporate network.)  You'll want to select the option to check both DHCP and DNS for the proxy file. [`WinHTTP AutoProxy Functions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384122(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN contains a code sample using this API and lots of supporting info. If this succeeds, you'll get back the proxy info you can then plug into your HTTP download code.  AFAIK, there is not an equivalent WinINet option to do a new WPAD detection automatically-- only WinHTTP.
4. Next you can try to look for Firefox proxy settings.  [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404729/how-can-i-change-firefoxs-proxy-settings-from-an-external-program/405665#405665) details information about the location and format of these settings so you can access them programmatically.
5. if that still fails, ask the user (in your UI) to check that their internet connection is actually connected. it's actually far more common for users to be disconnected than for all of the above proxy-detection steps to fail. ask the user to open up their browser to make sure they can get to an internet site-- if the steps above fail, their browser is likley unable to see the web. Once the user claims they're connected, repeat steps 1-3.
6. if all of above fail, the you really have little choice but to ask the user to manually specify their proxy info. You'll probably want to clone the proxy UI of IE or firefox, and turn those UI settings into the appropriate parameters to configure proxy options when you download that file.

Note that there's no magic to proxy detection-- your choices are use the user's settings, use the default computer settings, use a direct connection, use WPAD to find a PAC file, or ask the user. There is, unfortunately, no way to "make HTTP connections without the need to take care of proxy stuff".

BTW, although you could use WinHTTP only for proxy detection and then use WinINet for fetching the file, I'd suggest using WinHTTP for both parts.  When you want the most flexibility and control over your HTTP interaction (as well as better stability than WinINet), WinHTTP is preferable.

**UPDATE 2:**

J.J. had a good idea above-- I added a step for checking Firefox proxy settings. Since oddball proxies are generally found in corporate environments (which tend to standardize on IE) it's somewhat less likley that this will help, but it's worth a try.

**UPDATE:** I just edited the section above in response to Francis's correct comment: WinHTTP is not the "successor" to WinINet in a strict sense (meaning 100% of the features of WinINet are avilable in WinHTTP).  Rather, WinHTTP is designed for apps which are using HTTP for data-interchange and don't care about integrating with Interet Explorer's cache, cookies, dial-up UI, etc.

Server apps definitely fall into this category (WinHTTP, unlike WinINet, is safe for use in server apps) but lots of client software use it too, for example the Windows Update client on every modern PC.  In general, WinHTTP is preferable for a client app which needs to download files over HTTP and needs more fine-grained control over the networking and wants to control its own UI.

WinHTTP is more hands-on (for example, you need to make one API call to get proxy info and another to use that proxy info) but that extra degree of control allows you to do things you can't do with WinINet, like forcing ignoring the user's proxy settings and trying a new WPAD detection.

Comment: I think the procedure above is simply like doing all the stuff in sequence... Handling WPAD and PAC are also too complex for programs which simply want a HTTP connection.
Also according to MSDN, the WinHTTP is not successor of WinINET. It's for different (mostly for server side programming) purpose.

Comment: Hi Francis - I updated the answer above to respond to your comments. You're correct, the way to solve this problem is to perform a set of steps in sequence-- AFAIK there's no "repair the user's broken proxy info" function in WinINet or any other Windows API. I also added more info to clarify the sceanrios where you'd want to use WinINet vs. WinHTTP.

Comment: hi downvoter - want to comment about your concerns about this answer?  I'd be happy to revise accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The best description I've found of the process IE itself uses is in [How the Windows Update client determines which proxy server to use to connect to the Windows Update Web site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/900935).  Combine the sequence when using IE to access Windows Update with your knowledge of WinINet or WinHTTP [WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [WinHttpGetProxyForUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get your application connected.

Here's the sequence from the KB article:

1. If the user is configured to automatically detect settings, look for a PAC file using WPAD.
2. No PAC file found?  If the user has the IE automatic configuration script set, use that PAC file.
3. Still no PAC file found?  Look for a proxy.  If the user has manually configured IE proxy settings, use them.
4. No IE proxy configured?  Check the default proxy config.
5. No default proxy configured?  Use a direct connection.